# Regular expression matching a sequence of words

Tags: regex, pcre

Let's suppose we have a paragraph like this:

> Lorem ipsum, sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem - ipsum, sit
>   amet. Morbi a suscipit sem, quis finibus turpis. Lorem ipsum: sit
>   amet. Proin suscipit ac arcu pharetra tincidunt. Lorem ipsum. sit
>   amet. Pellentesque eu lacinia metus.  sit amet: Lorem ipsum. Lorem
>   turpis ipsum, sit amet.

I need a regex pcre pattern case insensitive that only selects the words

```
1 lorem
2 ipsum
3 sit
4 amet
```

in that specific order ignoring punctutation and occurrences like

```
Sit amet lorem ipsum
Lorem turpis ipsum, sit amet
```

Comment: Why the *I need*? - Please show your best try. SO is not a free code service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple straight forward with certain punctuation characters. You can append any punctuation character inside the []:

```
([Ll]orem)[\s,.!:\-()?]+(ipsum)[\s,.!:\-()?]+(sit)[\s,.!:\-()?]+(amet)
```

or everything that is a whitespace and not [A-Za-z0-9]

```
([Ll]orem)[\s\W]+(ipsum)[\s\W]+(sit)[\s\W]+(amet)
```

Case sensitivity can be an option to switch depending on the programming language. Or you have to manually add every relevant variation like ([L|l]orem)

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/PDVQdv/4)